# web2py displays id too

Tags: python, database, field, web2py

I got this code in default.py :

```
form_0 = SQLFORM(db.base_folder, record=db.base_folder(1))
query = db.base_folder.folder != ''
set = db(query)
rows = set.select()
if rows:
    form_0.vars.folder = rows[0]['folder']
```

and in db.py :

```
db.define_table(
'base_folder',
Field('folder',
      type='string',
      default='You need to set up a directory to backup to !',
    ),
    format='%(folder)s'
)
```

and unfortunately, the form displayed, displays also :

```
id: 1
```

above the field value. This issue disappears when I omit the record option.

How could I avoid that behavior please - as I need to keep the update
function ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQLFORM(db.base_folder, record=db.base_folder(1), showid=False)
```

Comment: I read the whole db doc, I didn't thought it could come from the form ^^.. Thanks to point out my d#*ness. ;)

Comment: Another option would be: `db.base_folder.id.readable = False`.